# Conditional Component variable value increment Vue/Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[1]so i have a laravel project going on, and i want to increment the value of the variable deliver_later_num, depending on the "deliver_today" present in the same component in the items[] array, which i am outputting in the template file, i cannot figure how to do it, i do not know if i can increment the value on the template side or on the component side. here is the component code:

```
 cartContent = new Vue({
        el: '#cartList',
        data: {
            items: [], //array containing all the items
            deliver_later_num: 0, //value to increment 
        },
        methods: {
            remove: function (product_id) {
                removeProductIfFromCart(product_id);
            },
            incQuantity: function (product_id){
                incCart(product_id)
            },
            decQuantity: function (product_id){
                decCart(product_id)
            },
           
        }
    })
```

here is the template file :

```
<div id="cartList">
                <div v-for="item in items" class="items col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 clearfix">
                    <div class="info-block block-info clearfix" v-cloak>
                        <div class="square-box pull-left">
                            <img :src="item.attributes.image"  class="productImage" width="100" height="105" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="product-item_title">@{{ item.name }}</h6>
                        <p class="product-item_quantity">@{{ item.quantity }} x @{{ item.attributes.friendly_price }}</p>
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <button v-on:click="decQuantity(item.id)" :value="item.id" class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <button v-on:click="incQuantity(item.id)" :value="item.id" class="page-link" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item">
                                <button v-on:click="remove(item.id)"  :value="item.id" class="page-link" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                </button>
                            </li>

                            <input hidden  class="delivers_today_state" type="text" :value=" item.attributes.delivers_today "> // if this equals 0 i want to increment the deliver_later_num value
                       

                        </ul>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

laravel controller code :

```
  public function add(Request $request){
    $item = Items::find($request->id);
    $restID=$item->category->restorant->id;

    //Check if added item is from the same restorant as previus items in cart
    $canAdd = false;
    if(Cart::getContent()->isEmpty()){
        $canAdd = true;
    }else{
        $canAdd = true;
        foreach (Cart::getContent() as $key => $cartItem) {
            if($cartItem->attributes->restorant_id."" != $restID.""){
                $canAdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //TODO - check if cart contains, if so, check if restorant is same as pervious one

   // Cart::clear();
    if($item && $canAdd){

        //are there any extras
        $cartItemPrice=$item->price;
        $cartItemName=$item->name;
        $theElement="";

        //Is there a varaint
        //variantID
        if($request->variantID){
            //Get the variant
            $variant=Variants::findOrFail($request->variantID);

            $cartItemPrice=$variant->price;
            $cartItemName=$item->name." ".$variant->optionsList;
            //$theElement.=$value." -- ".$item->extras()->findOrFail($value)->name."  --> ". $cartItemPrice." ->- ";
        }


        foreach ($request->extras as $key => $value) {

            $cartItemName.="\n+ ".$item->extras()->findOrFail($value)->name;
            $cartItemPrice+=$item->extras()->findOrFail($value)->price;
            $theElement.=$value." -- ".$item->extras()->findOrFail($value)->name."  --> ". $cartItemPrice." ->- ";
        }


        Cart::add((new \DateTime())->getTimestamp(), $cartItemName, $cartItemPrice, $request->quantity, array('id'=>$item->id,'variant'=>$request->variantID, 'extras'=>$request->extras,'restorant_id'=>$restID,'image'=>$item->icon,'friendly_price'=>  Money($cartItemPrice, env('CASHIER_CURRENCY','usd'),true)->format(),'delivers_today' => $item->deliverstoday ));


        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'errMsg' => $theElement
        ]);
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'errMsg' => __("You can't add items from other restaurant!")
        ]);
        //], 401);
    }
}

public function getContent(){
    //Cart::clear();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => Cart::getContent(),
        'total' => Cart::getSubTotal(),
        'status' => true,
        'errMsg' => ''
    ]);
}
```

link to the items array vue dev tools screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smLRV.png

thanks for your precious help and time.

Answer (score 0):

A computed property can be used if the deliver_later_num is only dependent on the presence/absence of deliver_today on elements of items array

```js
 cartContent = new Vue({
    el: '#cartList',
    data: {
        items: {}
    },

    computed: {
        deliver_later_num() {
            let num = 0;
            Object.keys(this.items).forEach(key => {
                let item = this.items[key];
                Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
                    if(k === 'deliver_today' && item[k]) {
                        num++;
                    }
                });
            });

            return num;
         },
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, when i added the code you provided, items won't add to cart anymore, and nothing is really showing in the interpolation field of deliver_later_num :/

Comment: How is the items array populated?

Comment: @HatemTEMIMI Have updated answer to use a computed property instead of watcher, pls check and let me know

Comment: same as before, it blocks me from adding items to the cart, with this error : "vue.js:437 TypeError: this.items.forEach is not a function". i tried removing the iteration block and initializing the num variable with num = 5, and it worked, so it must be the error i just indicated.

Comment: When you add items to the cart, what does devtools show for item - at any point is items not an array. Do you set it to null or any other type in any of your methods

Comment: i replaced the iteration block with a console.log(this.items) and it is of type Observable : __ob__: Observer}
1608047972: (...)
1608048726: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get 1608047972: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set 1608047972: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get 1608048726: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set 1608048726: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object

Comment: Don't you have vue devtools extenion installed? You can view the datatype and values with devtools. It's a kind of must have extension when developing with Vue. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#vue-devtools

Comment: i will add a screenshot of the value outputted of items[] via the vue dev tools to the post EDIT: i cannot add images so i have included a link to the image in the bottom of the post

Comment: It's clear that items is not an array but an object. Probably because of the way you are sending them from the Laravel controller. Will **deliver_today** be a first level key in child objects of items or will it be nested under attributes or some other key. If you can post the code for Laravel controller can try to see why items is being sent as object and not an array. Why there are 4  root components in devtools

Comment: i have included the laravel controller code for you, i hope we can figure out something, i am continuing over another developer's work, and it will probably be problematic to change the return type of the items.

Comment: @HatemTEMIMI Have updated the answer. Remove delivery_later_num from data property as it is now a computed property and initialize items as an empty object rather than an empty array. Pls check. And as suggested by you not changing the return types

Comment: it doesn't seem to work since there is no deliver_today attribute on the object you converted to an array, i will be trying a different approach, since i do think there is no way out with this approach without directly modifying the controller's return type, thank u for taking the time to help.